# execute shell command on remote machine

Tags: c#, .net, process, command, wmi

I was just creating a small tool to execute shell commands on remote machine and get output and errors.

I am running my application under all privileges.

Example : I should be able to run dir /a on remote machine and get output and so on for other commands.

I just browsed for it and found that psexec is a tool provided to do this task. But I want to do this using .net framework.

If I will used WMI then I can't know when then process is finished and read output.

Anyone have done that before.

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you know when it's done?  And you can log or pipe output if you want to see it.

Comment: because i want to find a simple .net solution before working with WMI

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to do something like Remote debugging for development purposes?

If so : Try Remote Debugging in visual studio. 
Start: Visual Studio > Visual Studio Tools > Visual Studio Remote Debugger

Comment: no i dont want to do so. I am creating an application which will do above mentioned thing for user.